# keyboard shortcut in java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I want to add a sort of cheat code to a program I am writing.  I was wondering how I could do this.  For example when I am anywhere on the screen I want to be able to press a certain key combination for example ctl + alt + w, and get some action from that.  My guess would be using a keylistener and adding it to the frame.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

```
class cheat implements KeyListener{

      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

          char key = e.getKeyChar();

          System.out.println(key);

      }
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}



      }
```

Comment: What type of program is this?  Swing?

Comment: That's a reasonable guess; did you try it?

Comment: No, you should NOT use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to  be used with Key Bindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you would add a keylistener. Inside your trigger for your listener, you can pass the KeyEvent to a secondary method to encapsulate the logic, then act appropriately.

```
isCheatCode(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        int mods = e.getModifiers();
        return (mods & InputEvent.ALT_MASK != 0)
        && mods & InputEvent.CTRL_MASK != 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I created a simple listener and added to the frame but nothing is happening.

Comment: Let's see your trigger method.

Comment: I see. That's not exactly going to work :-) How big is the entire project, in lines of code?

Comment: Well, it's never checking the keys to see what's being pressed (like in my code snippet) and two it doesn't have access to the information in your original class. How many other keylisteners are being added to the frame? Is it just one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4850/discussion-between-user541597-and-glowcoder)

Comment: No you should not use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to use Key Bindings for this purpose.

Comment: @camickr I don't know about should or should not. I don't see any particular reasons why KeyListener wouldn't do the exact same thing, and (personally) I feel it's lighter weight to use KeyListener instead. *shrug* I wouldn't recommend *against* using Key Bindings, but to say that KeyListener shouldn't be used is a stretch. Unless you have some compelling evidence?

Comment: Its never an absolute rule but in general as I said Swing was designed to use Key Bindings. I try to promote using Swing the way it was designed. This case would definately qualify. It is generally better to use a higher level API when available. Bindings promote the use of Actions. Another advantage is that bindings can be configured to work whether the component has focus or not.   KeyListeners where used with AWT because there was no altenative. See [Key Binding List](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of bindings by component.

Comment: @camickr But it really seems that the bindings only work for a specific set of default actions. Could you post an example of how they might work for something other than those defaults where they're baked into the component?

Comment: Exactly. Each component has a predefined set of Actions. If you want to add additional behaviour you create a custom Action and then bind the Action to a KeyStroke. Actions can also be added to JButtons and JMenuItems, so now you have a complete UI for the same Action. Have you ever used an `accelerator` in a JMenuItem. This is implemented as a key binding on the root pane of the frame. Have you ever used a `mnemonic` on a button? This is implemented as key bindings for the component. The example is the posters question. He wants to bind an `Action` to `Ctrl+Alt+W`.

Answer (score 3):

You can read about [How to Use Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) in Java Swing.

Comment: +1, for key bindings. Swing was designed to use key bindings for this type of requirement.

Answer (score 2):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html should be your starting point if you want to implement it in java

Comment: robot automates the click or typing event, I want to do it manually

Answer (score 2):

Well, in s Swing application you would do this sort of thing with KeyListeners along with KeyBinding. Take a look at the APIs and How-Tos

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Regards!

Comment: +1, for key bindings, -1 for KeyListner, nets out to no vote.